# Interpreting Green Chlorophyll Index vs NDVI

Tags: google-earth-engine, remote-sensing, ndvi, landsat, vegetation-index

I am attempting to research the relationship between agricultural yields and household well-being, and I am using remote sensed vegetation indices calculated from LANDSAT images to do this. Whereas NDVI Green NDVI have easy to understand -1 to 1 scales, I have been unable to find an interpretation of the values for the Green Chlorophyll Index.

Does anyone have any resources I could use to better understand the GCI scale, and what different levels of GCI mean?

Comment: List compilation Questions are off-topic here. You're better off asking Google for resources. If instead you asked for direct information, much like the Answer provides, then this wouldn't be a compilation question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't have access, but perhaps you have a access through your organisation: Comparison of different reflectance indices for vegetation analysis using Landsat-TM data
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S2352938518300302

I only know that it's a stress index, and that GCI (Green Chlorophyll Index) is used to estimate leaf chlorophyll content in the plants based on near-infrared and green bands. In general, the chlorophyll value directly reflects the vegetation.

The GCI formula looks like GCI = NIR / Green – 1.

So I think that high values are better than low values, if both NIR and G are normalised. In the link you can see an example:
https://geopard.tech/blog/kc9y2x96kv-which-vegetation-index-is-better-to-use/